# Cassandra: MigrationStage cannot keep up

Tags: schema, backlog

We have 4 nodes and running tpstats shows big backlog for MigrationStage at all nodes and it's not able to reduce the queue over time. For example:

Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
MigrationStage                    1      3946          17766         0                 0

I don't see this going down ever and the other 3 servers have about 300 pending requests.
Is there a way to speed this up? Or is it possible to stop schema migration since most likely it's trying to migrate old keyspaces?

PS I Tried to drop keyspaces to reduce this (there are about 200 keyspace). However I always query timeout for that statement (select works). I assume this backlog is also blocking some schema DLL statements.